# How do I disambiguate enums from fields without specifying the namespace?

Tags: c#, enums

```
enum SameName { Value }
class Tester
{
   void Method1() {
      SameName SameName;
      SameName test = SameName.Value;
   }
   void Method2() {
      string SameName;
      SameName test = SameName.Value;
   }
}
```

In the first method, the compiler correctly divines that SameName.Value refers to the enum.

In the second method, the compiler gets confused and thinks that SameName.Value is referring to a Value member of the string class. Since no such member exists, it errors.

What can I do to help make the compiler more aware of my SameName enum in this context? Is there some way to do this with using statements?

- I can't rename the variable or the enum in my real code.
- I'm creating a large dictionary with many enum values, and I'd rather not add the namespace prefix in front of each instance of the enum.

**Update:** Yes, I know I shouldn't use capitalized local variables. Yes, I realize these are local variables, not fields. Yes, I realize that this would be terrible to debug if the real code looked like this. I wrote the above as a short, contrived example that shows the problem I'm having in real code. I apologize that I did not make my intent clear. In the real code, the class is in a namespace contained within the enum's namespace, and the local variable is a property in a base class. I've tried to remove all that extraneous code to make the concern easier to spot, and listed my requirements to give a little scope for the problem.

Comment: Your examples don't use fields, but local variables that violate the naming conventions for local variables.

Comment: Um. Don't do that? Why name local variables the same as a type? It only leads to confusion.

Comment: So, why is the reason for not using the Full Qualified name? That is exactly the cause for use the namespace prefix to the classes, enums, structs, etc

Comment: "I'd rather not add the namespace prefix in front of each instance of the enum." Don't be lazy, if you wrote this code than you dug your own grave here. I'd hate to be the guy debugging your code a few months from now. Why not add the namespace prefix for readability purposes? Plus it would solve this issue. There's really no good reason to NOT add the namespace prefix.

Comment: Upvoted because I find it interesting that there's a difference between `Method1` and `Method2`. I want to check which rule of the C# Spec makes the two situations non-equivalent.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: The rule is that when doing a type lookup for `SameName` the compiler does not search the local declaration space because obviously there cannot be a type there. It matches the type. But in `SameName.Value`, expression `SameName` matches the local, which does not have a property `Value`. Do a search in the spec for "Color Color" for an interesting exception to this rule.

Comment: @EricLippert I provided an "answer" below where some consequences are seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, based on your update, I think we can help you. The situation makes more sense now. I suppose there's code:

```
// in a place you're not allowed to edit
namespace Outer
{
  public enum SameName { Value, }
}
```

and

```
// in a place you're not allowed to edit
namespace BaseSpace
{
  public class TesterBase
  {
    public string SameName { get; set; }
  }
}
```

and then you have the problem in a third code file which you *can* edit. I suggest you solve it with a [`using` alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) pointing to the type. Then you won't have to repeat the full namespace over and over again. It will look like this:

```
using BaseSpace;
using snEnum = Outer.SameName;          // this helps you (a using alias)

namespace Outer.Inner
{
  public class Tester : TesterBase
  {
    void Method2() {
      snEnum test = snEnum.Value;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that using alias directives can "point" either to a namespace or to a type (like in this case). They give you a shorthand for a cumbersome name that you use a lot.

Comment: thank you for the clear description on aliases. I was able to take this information to my stakeholders and explain why I should be allowed to specify the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an *alias* for the enum type:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    using NewEnumName = ConsoleApplication13.SameName;

    internal enum SameName { Value }

    internal class Tester
    {
        private void Method1()
        {
            SameName SameName;
            SameName test = SameName.Value;
        }

        private void Method2()
        {
            string SameName;
            SameName test = NewEnumName.Value;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C# was designed to be robust in the face of a *property* named the same as its type because this is common:

```
class Shape
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    ...
```

If you have a type Color, it is very common to have a property also called Color, and there's no good way to rename either of them.  Therefore C# was designed to handle this situation reasonably elegantly.  See my 2009 article for some interesting details about the Color Color problem:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/06/color-color.aspx

C# was *not* designed to handle the Color Color problem when the thing being declared is a local. **Rename your local**.

Comment: Even if the Original Question seems to present a somewhat silly situation, why is `Method1` allowed, but `Method2` is not? This surprises me. Because in both situations a _local variable_ has the same name as a _type_ (the type being in the same namespace as the current type, but not nested inside the current type). So since you know the C# Spec very well, maybe you can tell right away where this difference comes from?

Comment: Tested a bit. `Method1` remains valid if we change `SameName` from an `enum` to a `class` (where the class has an accessible `static` field called `Value`). The reason why they can allow this without getting into trouble, seems to be that it's very hard to give `SameName` two members, one static and one non-static, both with the same name. With `Method2`, on the other hand, you can easily give `SameName` type a static member with the same name as one of the instance members of `System.String`. And that would be a severe ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better to use the convention for naming local variables, `sameName`, for reasons just such as this.  Here's a full example:

```
enum SameName { Value }
class Tester
{
   void Method1() {
      SameName sameName;
      SameName test = SameName.Value;
   }
   void Method2() {
      string sameName;
      SameName test = SameName.Value;
   }
}
```

You say that you can't rename the field, but your example shows local variables.  It's a convention that fields should only be private, and don't start with a capital letter.  Local variables and private fields can, with rare exception (such as reflection...and if you're reflecting private fields, you've got other issues), always be renamed to suit whatever you need.

In short, use good practices and you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer. Rather an observation inspired by the question:

QUIZ: What does this code output (given that `System.Object` has *instance* methods `ToString()` and `GetHashCode()`)?

```
class Color
{
  private static new int ToString()
  { return 42; }
  public static new string GetHashCode()
  { return "I'm public!"; }
}

static class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Color Color = new Color();
    var testA = Color.ToString();
    var testB = Color.GetHashCode();
    Console.WriteLine(testA);
    Console.WriteLine(testB);
  }
}
```

Answer: Since `Color` defines new static methods with the same names and signatures as its inherited instance methods, the compiler can choose two overloads. In the case of `ToString` it chooses the instance method, which is lucky because the static method is private. But withe `GetHashCode` it chooses the static method. Color-Color magic.

Added remark: To those who have objections to naming a local variable with capital initial letter, the same example can be made when Color-Color is a direct class member, for example `public static Color Color { get; set; }`.