# Nullable enums does not contain error

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, nullable

I would like to create my enums as nullable rather than add a default entry with a default of  0.

However, in the following scenario I get syntax errors and I can't understand why, or how to fix it at the moment. It's probably something simple, but the simplest things...

Here's my properties that decare enums as nullable:

```
public Gender? Gender { get; private set; }

public MaritalStatus? MaritalStatus { get; private set; }
```

Here's a method that is giving me the syntax error, which is Gender does not contain..., MaritalStatus does not contain...:

```
    string GetTitle()
    {
        if (Gender == null || MaritalStatus == null)
            return null;
        if (Gender == Gender.M) // Error here!
            return "Mr";
        else if (
            MaritalStatus == MaritalStatus.Married ||
            MaritalStatus == MaritalStatus.Separated ||
            MaritalStatus == MaritalStatus.Widowed) // Error here!
            return "Mrs";
        else
            return "Ms";
    }
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: try specifying `this.Gender == Gender.M`

Comment: Almost Ned - it wasn't enough to add this but this worked this.Gender == DataLists.Gender.M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have enums `MaritalStatus` and `Gender`. At the same time, you have properties named `MaritalStatus` and `Gender`. You need to avoid this.

Here:

```
if (Gender == Gender.M)
if (MaritalStatus == MaritalStatus.Married)
```

the syntax is incorrect since `Gender` and `MaritalStatus` are recognized as variables, but not as type.
Moreover, you need to use `.Value` to access a value of `Nullable`.

So, you can explicitly specify the namespace:

```
if (Gender.Value == YourNamespace.Gender.M)
if (MaritalStatus.Value == YourNamespace.MaritalStatus.Married)
```

but I strongly recommend to rename your enums to `GenderEnum` and `MaritalStatusEnum`.

### Why does it happen?

This problem is simply reproducable here:

```
enum SameName { Value }
class Tester
{
   void Method1() {
      SameName SameName;
      SameName test = SameName.Value; // Works!
   }
   void Method2() {
      string SameName;
      SameName test = SameName.Value; // Doesn't work! Expects string method Value
   }
}
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15976488/3218692) Eric Lippert has described the reason of this:

> C# was designed to be robust in the face of a property named the same as its type because this is common:

```
class Shape
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    ...
```

> If you have a type Color, it is very common to have a property also called Color, and there's no good way to rename either of them. Therefore C# was designed to handle this situation reasonably elegantly.

So, if your variable is of type `Enum`, then it refers to the enum member; else - it refers to variable. `Enum?` belongs to "else".

Comment: Can you explain why the above works when the property type is not nullable enum, but just enum?

Comment: @IvanStoev I have tried to give an explanation, but simply haven't found it. It looks like it recognizes that `Gender.` will refer to enum type. However, in case it is not a `Enum` (including `Enum?`), it refers to a variable. It even doesn't work for `int`. Look: **[works](http://ideone.com/wzW0cP)** and **[doesn't](http://ideone.com/JIOeeh)**. I would appreciate if someone else gives this explanations :)

Comment: Yeah, I know. Just a quite annoying that adding a single `?` in the property definition breaks the existing code inside the class.